# codeblocks linker makes -lusb-1.0.lib out of libusb-1.0.lib and says ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0.lib

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw, codeblocks, linker-errors

The linker of codeblocks won´t find my a library because he uses the -l option incorrect. The name of the library is libusb-1.0.lib. The linker knows the path and he knows about the lib, because i told him via project/build options.

The linker usually makes -lusb-1.0 out of libusb-1.0.lib but not the codeblocks linker. He makes -lubs-1.0.lib out of it. With this -l option he wont find the lib. Am i wrong.

[linker -l option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL6KB.png)

Even putting the -l option by my self in project/build options/linker settings/other linker options: -lusb-1.0 wont work.

Somebody got an idea what is happening here? Or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no "codeblocks linker". It is the MinGW GCC linker. No-one can tell what you are doing wrong unless you show us the linker
command that is failing and the linker error message. You will find them in the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab) after your build fails. Post this information in the question, not in comments.